# Filter Entries by Custom date

Tags: craft3

I want to output all entries which match with a given year from a custom date field. The year is a string I get from slug. I am using Craft 3.5.16. What did I do wrong?

```
{% set catYear = craft.app.request.segment(-1) %}

{% set firstDayOfYear = now | date_modify('1 January ' ~ catYear) %}
{% set lastDayOfYear = now | date_modify('31 December ' ~ catYear) %}

{% set params = {
  section : 'termine',
  datumTermin : 'and, >= ' ~ firstDayOfYear|date ~ ', <= ' ~ lastDayOfYear|date
} %}

{% set beitrage = craft.entries(params).all %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to query using strings and your condition should be written as follow:

```
{% set catYear = craft.app.request.segment(-1) %}

{% set firstDayOfYear = catYear ~ "-01-01" %}
{% set lastDayOfYear = catYear ~ "-12-31" %}


{% set params = {
    section : 'termine',
    datumTermin : ['and', '>=' ~ firstDayOfYear, '<= ' ~ lastDayOfYear]
} %}

{% set beitrage = craft.entries(params).all %}
```

[See documentation for reference](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/date-time-fields.html#querying-elements-with-date-fields) :)

Comment: I tested your code in my environment. It works.

Comment: @thomas I deleted your answer since it wasn’t an answer and converted it to a comment here. If Oli’s answer solved the problem for you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

**Bonus Answer:** You can use after and before for that as well like below code.

```
{% set catYear = craft.app.request.segment(-1) %}

{% set firstDayOfYear = catYear ~ "-01-01" %}
{% set firstDayOfNextYear = firstDayOfYear | date_modify('+1 year') %}
{% set beitrage = craft.entries.after(firstDayOfYear|atom).before(firstDayOfNextYear|atom).all %}
```